# How can I get six sided pillars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I get a 6 sided quartz pillar block? I do have world edit on my server, and I can get 6 sided logs, I just can't figure out how to do it with Pillars.

Comment: How did you get six-sided logs? Using mods?

Answer (score 1):

## It's impossible.

There just is no six sided pillar block. Quartz blocks have five different states: regular, chiselled, vertical pillar, north-south pillar, east-west pillar. A six sided pillar doesn't exist in the game.

Comment: Now the wiki actually has an image of a three-sided quartz pillar, but as far as I can tell it's still not in the game.